# Beamer template shows itemize circles as squares (but the symbol is a circle)

Tags: beamer, itemize, templates, circles

I created my custom Beamer template to include background graphics, logo, etc. I also changed the colour of texts, bullet points to match the images colours.

The problem I have is that the circles in the itemize environment are displayed as squares, but when I copy and paste the symbol in a text editor they are really circles (\textbullet in LaTeX).

I have the theme file plus images, these are the definitions.

---

beamerthememytheme.sty

```
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% Set graphics path
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% Set main font for the presentation
% Note: the following fonts need to be installed
\setmainfont{Open Sans}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}

% tikz settings
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Settings
%\useinnertheme{mytheme}
%\useoutertheme{mytheme}
%\usecolortheme{mytheme}

% here the relevant content from theme files (the ones commented above)

\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{31,153,215}
\definecolor{subtitlecolor}{RGB}{163,162,162}
\definecolor{listscolor}{RGB}{31,153,215}

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=titlecolor}
\setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=subtitlecolor}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{itemize item}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{itemize subitem}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{itemize subsubitem}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=listscolor, bg=white}

% end content

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\mode<all>
```

---

Test.tex

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610, 8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{mytheme}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{\small{Subtitle}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                    SLIDE                    %%
\begin{frame}{Slide1}

Some text here...

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Sub item 1
        \item Sub item 2
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

And in the attached image there is the result of the compilation with XeLaTeX (I use custom fonts)

[image: Result]

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this issue?

Note: if I use one of the default themes it works and displays the circles correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could make a ready to copy&paste example, without the need to create several individual files.

Comment: I will edit the question removing the parts that are not relevant (although not knowing where the problem is it seemed correct to add all code)

Comment: Finding out which parts of the code are relevant is actually very easy, make a copy of your project and start to remove parts of the code. If the problem is still there, this block is probably irrelevant. If the problem vanishes, than the code is relevant for the example. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will increase you chances to get an answer, as you don't have to wait for a user with the necessary knowledge to have your non-standard fonts - I am not able to help you, as I cannot compile your example.

Comment: MWE: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\frame{\textbullet}
\end{document}
`

Answer (score 2):

This is extended comment ... from your code I find essential only this part:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610, 8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{fontspec}   % <-- source of the problem

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Slide1}    
Some text here...   
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Sub item 1
        \item Sub item 2
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}    
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

and it produce circles for items:

[image]

Well, `mytheme` is unknown as well your custom fonts ... above result I obtained with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` to your code turned the circles into squares for me: can you confirm?

Comment: yes, I can confirm this. it seems that problem is cause by this. I hope, that OP will use my MWE and add `\usepackage{fontspec}` to it. As I said, my answer is extended comment ...